# Active Directory PowerShell script to copy user properties

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Is there a script that can copy `Member Of` properties to a new user in Active Directory?

Comment: You're looking to give a new user the same membership as another user, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

The below should work... with 'User1' being the user being copied and 'User2' being the user to add to the groups:

```
Get-ADUser -Identity User1 -Properties memberof | Select-Object -ExpandProperty memberof | Add-ADGroupMember -Members User2
```

Comment: Would I have to specify a path?

Comment: I may have misunderstood your original request, as Santiago asked, Are you looking to give a new user the same membership as another user?  If yes, no path is needed, just replace User1 and User2 with the usernames.